# How to change usb mount rules?

Tags: pantheon-files, mount

Is there any way to change the mount rules on [files](/questions/tagged/files)?

It's `showexec` by default and I need it to mount as `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

Files uses GLib functions for mounting and they do not provide any MountFlags to influence this.  Maybe we could use the Linux.mount function, which does allow control over such options.

I suggest raising a wishlist issue on GitHub at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.